# UnboundLocalError, I am in an Intro class so i need it dumbed down as to how i go about fixing this error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get that the error is with getSales being refrenced before assignment but I do not understand how I fix that. I am a first semester into to programming class so I've read other questions with the same error but I cant grasp the concept of how it affects my code. I apologize that this is very much a repeat question.

```
def main():
    monthlySales = getSales() #call to get sales
    salesIncrease = getIncrease() #call to get sales increase
    storeAmount = storeBonus(monthlySales) #call to get the store bonus
    empAmount = empBonus(salesIncrease) #call to get the employee bonus
    printBonus = printBonus(storeAmount, empAmount) #call to print amounts



#This function gets the monthly sales
    def getSales():
        monthlySales = input('Enter the monthly sales $')
        monthlySales = float(monthlySales)
        return monthlySales

#This function gets the percent of increase in sales
    def getIncrease():
        salesIncrease = input('Enter percent of sales increase. For Example 4% should be entered as 4: ')
        salesIncrease = float(salesIncrease)
        salesIncrease = salesIncrease / 100
        return salesIncrease

#This function determines the storeAmount bonus
    def storeBonus(monthlySales):
        if monthlySales >=110000:
            storeAmount = 6000
        elif monthlySales >=100000:
            storeAmount = 5000
        elif monthlySales >=90000:
            storeAmount = 4000
        elif monthlySales >= 80000:
            storeAmount = 3000
        else:
            storeAmount = 0
        return storeAmount

#This function determines the empAmount bonus
    def empBonus(salesIncrease):
        if salesIncrease >= 5:
            empAmount = 75
        if salesIncrease >= 4:
            empAmount = 50
        if salesIncrease >= 3:
            empAmount = 40
        return empAmount


#This function prints the bonus information
    def printBonus(storeAmount, empAmount):
        print 'The store bonus amount is $', storeAmount
        print 'The employee bonus amount is $', empAmount
        if storeAmount == 6000 and empAmount == 75:
            print 'Congrats! You have reached the highest bonus amounts possible!'

#calls main
main()
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. All of your functions are defined *inside* the `main` function. Remove the extra indent so that your functions are defined in the global scope.

Comment: I went through and fixed the indentations but now it gets all the way down to printBonus and throws the same error that its refrenced before assignment. Also fixed elif in a few spots.

Comment: Stop using the `printBonus` name for two things at once. Pick a second name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, your indentation is off.  However, I understand you have now fixed this, but you get the error that `printBonus` is referenced before assignment.

The problematic line is this:

```
    printBonus = printBonus(storeAmount, empAmount) #call to print amounts
```

The problem here is that you have a local variable named `printBonus`, as well as a function named `printBonus`.  Inside the `main` function, the local variable takes precedence, so whenever the function refers to `printBonus` it will refer to the local variable.

In the line above, before Python can assign a value to `printBonus`, it first has to figure out what that value is.  However, this appears to be done by 'calling' this same `printBonus` thing, which is a variable that hasn't yet been assigned a value.

The simplest fix is not assign any local variable to the result of calling `printBonus`, given that it doesn't `return` anything:

```
    printBonus(storeAmount, empAmount) #call to print amounts
```

No local variable with the name `printBonus` means that within the `main` function, `printBonus` will refer to your function `printBonus()`, as intended.

You also say that you have 'fixed a few `elif`s'.  I can't see what changes you have made, but you might want to check that your `empBonus` function handles the case where `salesIncrease` is less than 3.